# jQuery Fancybox trigger

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I use fancybox to open a popup window with a form. At the moment popup comes to life when mouse leaves main page. In order to make this work i have a hidden link tag which i simulate with trigger() function that is clicked in order that link's href which is forms id with fancybox to come in life. Code as follows:

```
<a id="trigger" href="#feedback_form" style="display:none"></a>


$(document).mouseleave(function() {

//Triggers popup
$("#trigger").fancybox().trigger('click'); 

     //Popup function
     $("#trigger").fancybox({

     });

 });
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1** : hidden link and two functions :

1.1 Bind fancybox to selector :

```
$("#trigger").fancybox();
```

1.2 Then trigger the selector :

```
$("#trigger").trigger('click');
```

**Option 2** : hidden link and a single function :

```
$(document).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#trigger").fancybox().trigger('click');
});​
```

See : **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fEeqf/)**

**Option 3** (recommended): NO hidden link and a single function :

```
$(document).mouseleave(function() {
    $.fancybox("#feedback_form");
});​
```

See : **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmqzV/)**

Comment: I did that but a box with "#feedback_form" as content appears it renders it as html content.

Comment: @marios : yep, it's fancybox v2.1.3 ... the way you presented your code, the form is an online (hidden) in your document, isn't it? otherwise you need to provide more information or show your code. I think the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmqzV/) is quite specific.

Comment: Check please here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498274/fancybox-iframe-form-manipulation-with-ajax

Comment: Option 2 not usable, window flashes every click on it. Use option 3, best variant !

Answer (score 0):

You could also maybe use mouseout:

```
$(document).mouseout(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Not sure if that's much of a help tbh but it may be slightly better than mouseleave which was originally an IE only event.

Answer (score -2):

you can simply do this:

```
$(document).mouseleave(function() {

//Triggers popup
jQuery.fancybox({

href:$('yourcontentSelector');

 });

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this shows message that request cannot be delivered only when i changed it to                                                    'href':"$('yourcontentSelector')"