# Fancybox iframe form manipulation - with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have created a form popup that rises with a hidden trigger on mouseleave of the page. That way i ran full check of values entered and then with ajax data went to php for an email to be sent. Till then all were fine. Now i need to remove html content from index.html and add it from an external file for example called form.html. I 've decided to use iframe so i ve managed to make the form appear as a popup nice but the form submission or entered values check now fail. I am using old fancybox version not version no2. All controls where held with jQuery selectors etc, now even button "Submit" click is not recognised. Then i thought what about on() function so i wrote

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() { ... });
```

But nothing same issue. Any ideas? Maybe i dont have to use iframe but ajax to load content and then on(). I have tried that too but i had issues with popup content form that could not show up properly.

This is all the progress i ve done till now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';

//Bring form.html content with ajax into the page
$('body').append('<a id="trigger" href="#form_id"></a>');

//Check for mobile device, if jQuery.browser.mobile is false then we have a desktop or a laptop
if(!jQuery.browser.mobile)
{

    //Popup is triggered when mouseleave effect happens
    $(document).mouseleave(function() {

        'use strict';
        //Check if cookie popup already exists
        var popupCookie = COOKIE.getCookie('popup');

        //If it is then popup doesn't show
        if(!popupCookie)
        {//Popup appears but a popup cookie is set with duration set to 24 hours from now

            //Set expiration limit in 24 hours
            var expire = new Date();
            var time = expire.getTime();
            time += 24 * 3600 * 1000;//Exactly 24 hours from now
            expire.setTime(time);

            //Set a popup cookie
            COOKIE.setCookie('popup', 'popup', expire);

            $("#trigger").fancybox();
            //Triggers popup
            $("#trigger").trigger('click');

$.ajax({
  url: "form.html",
  success: function(data){
   $('body').append(data);
  }
});

            //Reset values
            $('input:text').val('');
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('#fancybox-content').css('background-color','#fff');          

            //Popup form function
            $("#trigger").fancybox({
                'scrolling'         : 'no',
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'onClosed'          : function() {
                                        $('input:text').val('');
                                        $('textarea').val('');
                                    },
                'autoDimensions'    : true,
                'padding'           : 5,
                'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
                'onStart'           : function(){
                                        $('#fancybox-content').css('background-color','#fff');                  
                                    }
            }); 

    $("#submit").on('click', function() { ... });
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: are you loading jQuery in that page? when using iframes, pages are totally independent animals so they need their own individual functionality

Comment: So js must be in iframe independent from js in the index.html right? But i do not want to include any js there. So this idea of mine was trash. Did not thought about, i thought it was like ajax fetch. (Still learning..) Before i had tried by fetching with ajax whole content from form.html as hidden then tried to trigger popup so had to change forms visibility before popup to visible but form did not appear correctly there. And then i had to make this hidden again etc so this whole concept seemed to me very complicated and useless. Any ideas? Client wants load from external source.

Comment: You could actually pull the form into your document via ajax instead of iframe so the scripts and style that the form will use will be in the index page. On the other hand you could also get some values from the index page and pass them to the form.html if using iframe ... but the form.html HAS to HAVE their own jQuery and scripts if you want to add `.on()` submit functionality.

Comment: I guess you need to post the code you are working with .... me personally don't have too much time to write a full solution from scratch (for free ;)

Comment: I will post the code in a min if you show some patience please